# preg_match double quota or Single quotation

Tags: php, preg-match

when use **Single quotation marks**

```
preg_match("/Location:(.*?)\n/", 'Location: www.\n', $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

It prints:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

when use **double quotation marks**

```
preg_match("/Location:(.*?)\n/", "Location: www.\n", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

It prints

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Location: www.
' (length=15)
  1 => string ' www.' (length=5)
```

Why??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really anything to do with `preg_match`. When you use single quotes, your string doesn't end in a newline; it ends in a backslash followed by an n.

Comment: if it's a variable,  `preg_match("/Location:(.*?)\n/", $header, $matches);`  $header's char values: 69 70 71 0d 0a 72 73,  How to match the 0d 0a ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> #### Single quoted
>
> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character `'`).
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other **escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally** as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Comment: the situation is, I used curl_exec and get the http header back,`preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $this->response_headers, $matches);
$newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));` it does not match the headers

Comment: @user1337896 In double quotes `"\n"` is a newline character. In single quotes `'\n'` is literally backslash n. It doesn't get treated as an escape sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Take a Look May this helps you:

[preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)